# How to switch between SFML-drawing and OpenGL-drawing in C++ program?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I want to switch between drawing with SFML graphics module and drawing with OpenGL(glfw3 + glad + SFML/OpenGL.hpp), where switching is based on elapsed time. I tried to do it like this:

**main_loop:**

```
#include "glfw3.h"
#include"glad.h"
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

...

window->setActive(true);

if (elapsed_seconds % 2 == 0)
    draw_OpenGL(window); // window is sf::RenderWindow*
else
    draw_SFML(window);
```

**draw_OpenGL:**

```
void draw_OpenGL(..., sf::RenderWindow* window){

    ... // glUniform and other stuff

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shader);
    glBindTextureUnit(0, texture);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    window->display();
}
```

**draw_SFML:**

```
void draw_SFML(sf::RenderWindow* window){
    
    ... // Defining 'shape'

    window->pushGLStates();

    window->clear(sf::Color::Black);
    window->draw(shape);

    window->popGLStates();

    window->display();
}
```

I followed [official guide](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php), but didn't succeed - while OpenGl draws fine, instead of SFML-made picture it draws nothing and just swaps buffers. I think my problem is in `popGLStates`/`pushGLStates` lines, because both `draw_OpeGL` and `draw_SFML` work as expected if I'm not switching between them. I also looked at some exemples of SFML+OpenGl code, but as far as I saw, they were using `popGLStates`/`pushGLStates` the same way. Do someone know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's possible that SFML's graphics system is only able to handle state that can be pushed with the compatibility `glPushAttrib` and the like. And there is quite a bit of state that cannot be pushed/popped by these commands. Of particular note is the program currently in use, which overrides *large parts* of the compatibility API that SFML probably depends on.

Comment: [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas), I don't know why, but it seems like my compiler doesn't understand `glPushAttrib` command, with nor without `#include<GL/gl.h>`.